# how can i get the right value and set in text view with image pager adapter?

Tags: android, image, fragmentpageradapter

What I have is a class called `FullImageActivity2` which displays images and I can flip between images with a pager adapter also in this activity I have a `TextView` which should display an item id for each image and it takes it values from a string array. I could connect the `TextView` with the value but the value does not change when I flip the image, I mean that I want each image to be connected with it's id and when I flip the image it should change and display the correct image.

here is my activity code :

```
public class FullImageActivity2 extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image_activity2);
        String[] nameArray={"Su6670","SU10670","PB6670","PB10670"}; 
        TextView itemid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.itemid);
         //get intent data

 //Selected image id
Integer[] newArray={R.drawable.bottle1,R.drawable.bottle2,R.drawable.bottle3,R.drawable.bottle4};


    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, newArray);
    List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < imageAdapter.getCount(); i1++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i1]);

        itemid.setText(nameArray[i1]);

        images.add(imageView);
    }

    // Finally create the adapter
    ImagePagerAdapter imagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);
    for (int m=0; m<imagePagerAdapter.getCount();m++){
          itemid.setText(nameArray[m]);
    }

    }
}
```

and here is the image pager adapter code :

```
 public class ImagePagerAdapter  extends PagerAdapter{
            private List<ImageView> images;

            public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
                this.images = images;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
                container.addView(imageView);
                return imageView;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView(images.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return images.size();
            }


            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  return view == o;
            }
        }
```

it always display the value `PB10670` in the `TextView`. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set a `OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager` like

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0)
    {
        itemid.setText(nameArray[arg0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
    {
    }
});
```

This way whenever you flip your image the text in your `TextView` will change depending on the current position.

Comment: i should add this code in full image activity right?

Comment: yeah after you call `setAdapter` will be fine

Comment: but i want to ask you .. it fill data after i flip it .. and the first value remains null ... how can i get the first value before any flipping?